# javascript window.print(), passing number of copies as param

Tags: javascript

Is there any way that I can pass parameter value to javascript window.print() function. Suppose I would like to print 2 copies, but by default print dialog box shows 1.

Is there alternative function to call print and pass number of copies from browser?

Answer (score 6):

No, (un-)fortunately that's not possible.

I'd say this is a good thing; otherwise some sites would specify a high number and people who don't expect this would accidentally print lots of pages instead of just a single one.