# How to change the number of pages to print with a button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, button

It´s only for local works. I have a button and in the onclick event the next code:

```
windows.print();
```

How to change the number of copies to print? It´s possible with JavaScript?
I have several buttons and diferent numbers of copies configured.

[image]

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242695/javascript-window-print-passing-number-of-copies-as-param

Comment: And this for a possible workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24823264/how-to-set-the-number-of-copies-to-print-from-javascript